# iOS passing data from table cell to new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have a table cell that I created custom, and each table cell has a pointer to its own contact object. I want to pass that pointer to another view controller to show more detail on it. I created my segue from the table cell to the view controller in interface builder. I am having trouble passing my value over, this is my prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"contactDetailSegue"]) {
        ContactDetailViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        Contact *contactToSend = (ContactTableViewCell *)sender.contact;
        destination.contact = contactToSend;
    }
}
```

My problem is I don't quite understand the role of sender in the function, I believe if I use interface builder the way I did then sender will be the table cell chosen. Should I then be able to take my contact pointer and pass it to my destination? I currently have a "Property 'contact' not found on object of type '__strong id'"

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your problem i guess

```
 Contact *contactToSend = [(ContactTableViewCell *)sender contact];
```

`id` is generic datatype. Compiler is not finding a property of `contact` in the object `sender` of type id. So its giving error. But you can send any message on id type object so `[sender contact]`. ObjectiveC is a dynamic language `contact` message will send to the actual object at the run time. So `[sender contact]` code will work if the sender is `ContactTableViewCell` at the run time. You are getting the error because your type casting is not proper. Amar mentioned the correct one

```
((ContactTableViewCell *)sender).contact
```

Comment: This will also work, and it doesn't even require you to cast! . `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(ContactTableViewCell *)sender`

Answer (score 1):

`id` is an object of any type. That means the compiler won't let you run the methods of a specific class on it. Find out what it really is at runtime by using a breakpoint. It could be one of your table view cells but it might be something else depending on how you've wired it up. Cast the sender to the specific class it really is so the compiler knows what methods can be called on it.

Comment: If object is of type `id` you can use any method on it and it will compile without error. But at run time if `id` was a dictionary and you are calling `objectAtIndex` it will throw unrecognised selector message and crash.

Comment: if I am **sure** that I am only calling on the type of object (with my object) then am I safe with using a method? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. The compiler will give you a warning if you try to call a class specific method on a reference of type `id`. I'm so used to treating warnings as as compiler errors that I often forget to distinguish between them.

Comment: @user3667450 Yes, casting it to the correct type is safe if it is indeed of that type. Some people like to check using isKindOfClass first though. I wouldn't in this particular situation. You could even change the method signature so that the sender is one of your cells instead of `id`.